# How do I hide multiple div's with no content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="contentMachine">
    <div class="contentTop">
        <span class="ledbars" id="DeviceDemo_001-ledbars">
            <span class="ledBar ledbar-1"></span>
            <span class="ledBar ledbar-2"></span>
            <span class="ledBar ledbar-3"></span>
            <span class="ledBar ledbar-4"></span>
            <span class="ledBar ledbar-5"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeBox">
            <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-timestamp" class="timeimg"> </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
        <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-text"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This content box is generated. I want to hide it if there's no content being generated on the backend. How do I do it? I already tried

```
if ($('.contentMachine').is(':empty')) {
    $('.contentMachine').remove();
}
```

But it's still not hiding the div's

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1frh9ktv/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1frh9ktv/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to removed matched elements, so `:empty` selector with class selector to get the reference of empty elements then apply `.remove()` method

```
$('.contentMachine:empty').remove()
```

Comment: @ArdenC, Can you elaborate, what do you mean by empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo selector empty:

```
$('.contentMachine:empty').remove();
```

**Update:**

You can retrieve the content of contentMachine as a text then play with the result:

```js
$('.contentMachine').each(function () {
 var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.replace(/(\n|\s)*/mg, '');
  if (text === '') {
   $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentMachine">
                    <div class="contentTop">
                        <span class="ledbars" id="DeviceDemo_001-ledbars">
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-1"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-2"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-3"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-4"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-5"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="timeBox">

                         <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-timestamp" class="timeimg"> </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contentBox">
                        <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-text"></span>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="contentMachine">
                    <div class="contentTop">
                        <span class="ledbars" id="DeviceDemo_001-ledbarsd">
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-1"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-2"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-3"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-4"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-5"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="timeBox">

                         <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-timestampd" class="timeimg"> </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contentBox">
                        <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-textd">With content</span>
                    </div>
</div>
```

*Last update:*

You can achieve it by checking all empty element into `.contentMachine`:

```
$('.contentMachine :empty').remove();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9tsvLu84/1/)

Comment: Here I made a fiddle which do the staff: https://jsfiddle.net/9tsvLu84/

Comment: it removed even those with content

Comment: Try with: `$('.contentMachine :empty').remove();`

Comment: I wanna hide with all the other divs inside as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
content = $('.contentMachine').text();
content = $.trim(content);

if (content.length == 0) {
  $('.contentMachine').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `.contentMachine` this div completely has no text anywhere it will remove by this script. I do it with help of rejex.

```js
var regex = "/^.+\s.+$/" ;  
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($(".contentMachine").text().match(regex));
   if ($(".contentMachine").text().match(regex) ==null||      $(".contentMachine").text().match(regex) == 0) {
      $(".contentMachine").remove();
   }                                           
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentMachine">
                    <div class="contentTop">
                        <span class="ledbars" id="DeviceDemo_001-ledbars">
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-1"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-2"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-3"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-4"></span>
                            <span class="ledBar ledbar-5"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="timeBox">

                         <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-timestamp" class="timeimg"> </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contentBox">
                        <span id="DeviceDemo_001-content-text"></span>
                    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
jQuery( '.contentMachine:empty' ).remove();
```